# MySQL key length problems when adding a column

Tags: mysql, sql, text, alter, tinytext

I am having problems with modifying an existing table in MySQL. When adding a new column, MySQL complains about indexing on an existing column. Here is what I am seeing:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE test (name TINYTEXT, KEY(name(255)));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)

mysql> ALTER TABLE test ADD name2 TINYTEXT;
ERROR 1170 (42000): BLOB/TEXT column 'name' used in key specification without a key length
```

What am I doing wrong? I already have a key length on the key specification, and I'm not changing it anyways.

Comment: I can't reproduce it: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ba6ae

Comment: I am able to do this without error in MySQL 5.1. Not sure why you are getting an error. Maybe try using VARCHAR(255) instead of TINYTEXT

Comment: Perhaps the problem is fixed in MySQL 5.5.32 that SQL Fiddle is running. I'm stuck with 5.1 for now. I'm currently running 5.1.70, but I looked at the change logs, but don't see any relevant bug fixes in the later releases.

Comment: @CharlieMartin It appears to be dependent on the charset. If I create the table with `CHARSET=latin1`, it works, but with `CHARSET=utf8`, it fails.